# Two Types of Enumerate Items

Tags: lists, enumerate, indentation

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE
\bfseries

\begin{enumerate}
\item Item 1. 

\item Item 2.

\item Item 3.

\item Item 4.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

I would like to have two types of enumerate items: the first, `\item`, which does what it currently does; and the second, say `\itemb` which indents, say 10pt, before displaying the item's number and contents. In the case of the MWE, I would like to keep items 1 and 4 the same, while indenting items 2 and 3.

QUESTION: Is this possible; and if so, how may this be done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In adaption of @Vincent's answer, you could define `\itemb` as:

```
\newcommand*{\itemb}[1]{%
  \begin{enumerate}\item #1\end{enumerate}
}
```

But with this, you would need to use a regular argument for `\itemb`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{
    label=\arabic*.,
    topsep=\itemsep,
    before={\setcounter{enumii}{\value{enumi}}},
    after={\setcounter{enumi}{\value{enumii}}\vspace*{-\topsep}}
}
\newcommand*{\itemb}[1]{%
  \begin{enumerate}\item #1\end{enumerate}
}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE
\bfseries

\begin{enumerate}
\item Item 1.
\itemb{Item 2.}
\itemb{Item 3.}
\item Item 4.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

You may also move all options to the `enumerate` environment of command `\itemb` to not influence `enumerate` environments, that do not use `\itemb` but usual nesting.

Additionally you can use an optional argument of `\itemb` to influence the indent, e.g., using option `left` documented in [section 3.2 “Horizonal spacing of labels” of the `enumitem` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf#subsection.3.2) of the environment:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand*{\itemb}[2][0pt]{%
  \begin{enumerate}[
    label=\arabic*.,
    topsep=\itemsep,
    before={\setcounter{enumii}{\value{enumi}}},
    after={\setcounter{enumi}{\value{enumii}}\vspace*{-\topsep}},
    left=#1,
  ]
  \item #2\end{enumerate}
}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE
\bfseries

\begin{enumerate}
\item Item 1.
\itemb[\dimexpr-\leftmargin+\itemsep\relax]{Item 2.}
\itemb{Item 3.}
\itemb[20pt]{Item 4.}
\item Item 5.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

For more options to influence the horizontal indent and spacing see [the linked manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf).

However, if you are not already using package `enumitem` *and* if all your items are only single lines, there could also be a simpler solution:

```
\documentclass{book}
\newcommand*{\itemb}[2][0pt]{%
  \begingroup
    \setlength{\itemindent}{\dimexpr\leftmargin + #1\relax}%
    \item #2\par
  \endgroup
}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE
\bfseries

\begin{enumerate}
\item Item 1.
\itemb{Item 2.}
\itemb[-\leftmargin]{Item 3.}
\itemb[20pt]{Item 4.}
\item Item 5.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

But usually you would not like this suggestion, if you have items with several lines. In this case the options for horizontal spacing and the margins of package `enumitem` are much more comfortable.

Comment: Thank you. This works quite nicely. I have a question---how does one specify the amount of indentation (e.g., 10pt)?

Comment: @mlchristians See [the `enumitem` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf), currently section 3.2, i.e., option `left`.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do that is probably to nest another list inside the first one.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{
    label=\arabic*.,
    topsep=\itemsep,
    before={\setcounter{enumii}{\value{enumi}}},
    after={\setcounter{enumi}{\value{enumii}}\vspace*{-\topsep}}
}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE
\bfseries

\begin{enumerate}
\item Item 1.
\begin{enumerate}
\item Item 2.

\item Item 3.
\end{enumerate}
\item Item 4.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes; this produces a desired output for the MWE---but if there were many items, there would be many pairs of `\begin{emunerate}` `\end{enumerate}`. That is why I asked---if it is possible to define a second type of item (`\itemb`) so that whenever I wanted an indentation, instead of typing `\item`, I could simply type `\itemb`. Do you know of such a way?

Comment: @Vincent This solution and all the others (which are based on this one with some additions) changes the way enumerate level 2 behaves in the whole document, isn't it? So if in some place of the document I need the second level to be as usual (a), (b), (c) etc I can't have it. Is there a way to define a new enumerate list just for this nesting and not affect all the level 2 enumerate lists? Or should I set the enumerate lists from level 3 and above as I desire?

Comment: @MiltosP. See my edited answer on how to avoid influence to other `enumerate` environments.

Answer (score 0):

As User Cabohah modified Use Vincent's answer, I now slightly modify Cabohah's answer to allow horizontal adjustments of the "special" indented items.

I have seen Cabohah's comment, but I could not ascertain from the linked manual what the user meant by ``option left''---so, I offer the following alternative:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{
    label=\arabic*.,
    topsep=\itemsep,
    itemindent=0pt, % Adjusts the indent for the "\itemb" items 
    before={\setcounter{enumii}{\value{enumi}}},
    after={\setcounter{enumi}{\value{enumii}}\vspace*{-\topsep}}
}
\newcommand*{\itemb}[1]{%
  \begin{enumerate}\item #1\end{enumerate}
}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE
\bfseries

\begin{enumerate}
\item Item 1.
\itemb{Item 2.}
\itemb{Item 3.}
\item Item 4.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

which gives, as far as I can tell, the same output as the said user's answer:

[image]

But, moreover, by placing `itemindent=` where I have in the code, we can change the "0pt" above to some positive value (such as 15pt) to shift the b-items to the right; for example, with replacing `itemindent=0pt` by `itemindent=15pt`, gives

[image]

And, by replacing `itemindent=0pt` by, say, `itemindent=-15pt` yields:

[image]

It would be nice, though, to know specifically, what the said user meant by "section 3.2, i.e., option left."

Comment: I've shown using option `left` and how to avoid influence on usual nested `enumerate` environments in the edit of my answer. Please also note, that I've set a link to the manual, so finding the referenced section of the manual and the documentation of option `left` in that section shouldn't be a hard job. ;-)