# Horizontally Shifting Description Items of a Particular Type

Tags: horizontal-alignment, pdftex, indentation, enumitem, description

The question herein is a modification of that asked in [Two Types of Enumerate Items](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/663336/two-types-of-enumerate-items)

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}

% % % COMPILE WITH PDFLATEX
\setlist[description,2]{
    topsep=\itemsep,
    %itemindent=-35pt,
    %itemindent=35pt,
    before={\setcounter{enumii}{\value{enumi}}},
    after={\setcounter{enumi}{\value{enumii}}\vspace*{-\topsep}}
}


\newcommand*{\itemb}[1]{%
  \begin{description}\item #1\end{description}
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\normalsize
\bfseries

\begin{description}
\item Item 1.
\itemb{\lipsum[13]}
\itemb{\lipsum[13]}
\item Item 4.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

I would like to shift the two `\itemb`items (the ones with Latin) a specified amount either to the left or two the right. Moreover, I would like to keep the default `hangindent` in place.

I thought, perhaps, that `itemindent=-35pt` or `itemindent=35pt` placed where these are commented out would do that. But, however, when I run the code with `itemindent=-35pt`, I get

[image]

And when I run the code with

And when I run the code with `itemindent=35pt`, I get

[image]

neither of which, amounts to a pure shift of the said description items.

QUESTION: How may I globally (as I have many such items in the actual document) effect a shift of the `\itemb` items a specified amount, keeping intact, the default hanging indent? I compile the code with `pdflatex`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `leftmargin= <space>` to control the left margin.

[image: a]

```
\setlist[description,2]{
    topsep=\itemsep,
    itemindent=-35pt,
    leftmargin=70pt,
    before={\setcounter{enumii}{\value{enumi}}},
    after={\setcounter{enumi}{\value{enumii}}\vspace*{-\topsep}}
}
```

[image: b]

```
\setlist[description,2]{
    topsep=\itemsep,
    itemindent=-35pt,
    leftmargin=30pt,
    before={\setcounter{enumii}{\value{enumi}}},
    after={\setcounter{enumi}{\value{enumii}}\vspace*{-\topsep}}
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Simon Dispa.